# Cannot Access Anything

Tags: bash

I just downloaded *Ubuntu* and I am having trouble accessing my Desktop and I cannot find a solution online. I have tried:

```
cd Desktop

cd /Desktop

cd ~/Desktop

cd /home/username/Desktop
```

Every time I try something it says no file or directory found. Any thoughts?

When I do `cd ~/Desktop` it says `/home/username/Desktop: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new file on your desktop and name it whatever you want.
2. In Ubuntu 18.10 and earlier drag the new file into the terminal to show its full path. Here is an example of the result of dragging a file named myFile from the desktop into the terminal.

```
$ '/home/username/Desktop/myFile'
```

myFile is located in `/home/username/Desktop/` where `username` is replaced by your username. If the above example was the result you got on your computer, then `cd Desktop` would have worked, otherwise the result dragging myFile into the terminal will show the location of the Desktop directory.

Comment: **:D :D :D +1 for the detective work!**