# How can I install Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search?

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded a tar.gz file from [Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search](https://www.mersenne.org/). I extracted it in the terminal, but when I type

```
cd filename
```

The terminal says

```
no such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Access Anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081028/cannot-access-anything)

Comment: Not a dupe of that - most likely OP is just in the wrong directory. Target describes a very unusual situation. The real question is how to install the software, which was answered

Answer (score 2):

Installation from tarball depends on the what is inside that tarball. Moreover `cd` (or change director), as the name suggests, can only be used with directories or folder names instead of file name. If you are using folder name and still getting an error, then you need to check *existence* of the directory or permissions.

On Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search's [download page](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) point 4 says,

> Start the program!
>   Linux and FreeBSD users should run the program from the command line with a -m switch, i.e.
>
> ```
> ./mprime -m
> ```

I expect that you've extracted the tar into a folder, let's say GIMPS and that's on Desktop.
So, you need to run:

```
cd ~/Desktop/GIMPS
./mprime -m
```

Answer (score 0):

When I click on the tarball to download it, it downloads a file called *p95v294b8.linux64.tar.gz*. When I right-click it and select 'Extract Here`, a directory is extracted called *p95v294b8.linux64*.

To run the software, do:

```
cd ~/Downloads/p95v294b8.linux64
./mprime -m
```